# Is it possible to combine columns in one dataframe based on the contents of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am facing a probably very simple problem and got stuck. I have a dataframe (df1) and a second dataframe (df2), which I want to use as the recipe to combine columns of df1. The col names in df2 are supposed to be the new column names of the final dataframe

I know, I can do this directly using the dplyr mutate function without df2, but the idea is that I can automate the process with future changes in the grouping file.

This is an example dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = seq(1:5),
  A = c(10,15,20,90,1),
  B = c(10,15,5,10,1),
  C = c(10,15,5,10,1),
  D = c(1,20,34,12,5),
  E = c(2,23,34,12,5)
)
```

This is the dataframe I want to use to combine columns of df1. The goal is to have a new dataframe that preserves ID variable of df1 and columns Group_1 to Group_3. E.g. Group_1 should be "df$B + df$C"

```
df2 <- data.frame (
  Group_1 = c("B","C"),
  Group_2 = c("D","A"),
  Group_3 = ("E")
)
```

This is the result i am trying to achieve. Instead of doing it manually, I would like to use df2 as the recipe. Hope someone can help me out

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  select(ID) %>%
  mutate (Group_1 = df1$B + df1$C,
          Group_2 = df1$D + df1$A,
          Group_3 = df1$E )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using base R, where we loop over each column of `df2`, subset the columns from `df1` and take `rowSums` to get sum.

```
cbind(df1[1], sapply(df2, function(x) rowSums(df1[unique(x)])))

#  ID Group_1 Group_2 Group_3
#1  1      20      11       2
#2  2      30      35      23
#3  3      10      54      34
#4  4      20     102      12
#5  5       2       6       5
```

---

A similar approach with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 

bind_cols(df1[1], map_df(df2, ~rowSums(df1[unique(.x)])) )
```

This is after reading data in `df2` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
df2 <- data.frame (
   Group_1 = c("B","C"),
   Group_2 = c("D","A"),
   Group_3 = ("E"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. This is exactly what i was looking for and it works perfectly. Thanks for providing a tidiverse and a base R solution.